# Display text inside loop in C# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, loops

I have a loop in my windows form

inside the loop i should display the customer number that been processed inside the loop

but the textbox that shoud have the customer number freezes during the loop and none got displayed untill loop finishes.

any ides how to resolve this?

Comment: Trying to display things inside a loop is not a good idea. The UI must repaint on each iteration and the loop will be moving to fast for the display to be visible. Show us the errant code and maybe we can find a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Full reference is `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, or for a `using`, `System.Threading.Tasks`

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          // Any GUI control which you want to use within thread,
          // you need Invoke using GUI thread. I have declare a method below for this
          //Now use this method as
          ExecuteSecure(() => textBox1.Text = "Customer Id " + i);
          //... other code etc.
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
});


//---
private void ExecuteSecure(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action()));
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

or Use a `BackgroundWorker` if you want your `UI` to be updated in real time

Comment: I get this error Error 1 The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context  sProj\Form1.cs 86 17

Comment: `Task.Factory` was only introduced in `.NET Framework 4`. What is your .Net version?

Comment: @asmgx Full reference is `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, or for a using, `System.Threading.Tasks`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh() textbox to get updated customerID

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int16 customerID = 5000;

    for(Int16 i=0;i<=10000;i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = customerID.ToString();
        customerID++;
        textBox1.Refresh(); //this line will update show new value in textbox
    }
}
```

[image]

```
textBox1.Refresh(); //this line will update show new value in textbox
```

I hope it might helpful